# Scikit-learn regressors returns all zeros for features importances, why?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

For training I'm using around 500k records with about 15 unique features. When I fit it to either RandomForestRegressor or GradientBoostingRegressor, it barely takes any time to fit, and returns all zeros for all features importances. And then for the test data it makes the same very low prediction for the entire set which is very variable. Gives a negative, close to 0, score.

In the abstract sense, why could this be happening? Does this mean there is something wrong with the train data?

Comment: In abstract sense this means that model learned something trivial, and probably you have some errors in the code, data or preprocessing/postprocessing.

Comment: I saw that my y values are very small numbers. For example 2.23247463363e-05. But the data all checks out. These are what they should be. So anyway I multiplied my y train values by 1000. Then divided my prediction values by 1000. And now I no longer have this problem. Why is this?

Comment: Really hard to guess without data and code - provide these elements and we might be able to help

Comment: Presumably you have already found a solution? When encountering this issue, I first try reducing `min_samples_leaf` parameter.